# Android PushWooh Register device

Tags: android, push-notification, pushwoosh

In my Android project I introduced the service pushwoosh. 
In the examples I've seen that in the onCreate method launch:

```
//Register receivers for push notifications
registerReceivers();

//Create and start push manager
PushManager pushManager = PushManager.getInstance(this);

//Start push manager, this will count app open for Pushwoosh stats as well
try {
    pushManager.onStartup(this);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    //push notifications are not available or AndroidManifest.xml is not configured properly
}
//Register for push!
pushManager.registerForPushNotifications();
String token= PushManager.getPushToken(this);

checkMessage(getIntent());
```

1) I would like to know if I should do this every time you launch the application, or just do it on the first launch.

2) What is the onResume method and the method OnPause launch registerReceiver and unregisterReceivers?

Answer (score 0):

1.) According to Google, they recommend registering the device on each launch, because sometimes, device registration id's can change (if anything, you reduce the risk of a user unwillingly being unregistered and not knowing it!)

2.) As for onResume and onPause, they relate to the application's savedInstanceState. So, onPause (when the application is paused), you might want to do something. then, onResume is there to remind the application what Activity is supposed to be going on so the user can interact with it. They're really to make sure that the application doesn't prematurely kill activities it has started or intends to start when new ones come up. You can read more about it here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: Thanks! I got it. In the second question actually asked in simple words what it was for the receiver. 
Thank you.  @Dan